# Shared folder in Appengine connected not updating

Tags: android, google-app-engine, synchronization, android-c2dm

I made a Appengine connected Android project. Worked will. Made custom Entity Class and Service class and Datastore as shown in the [Tut:Customizing your project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_add_rpc).
My problem: When I add a new method to the Service class, and then using warning message, also update "Request file" but only in shared folder of the AppEngine. The changes are not taking effect in Shared folder of my Android-Project. The method that I used is described in [Fine Tuning your project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_tuning)
So how to make my Android project's shared folder to update with the Appengine-projects Shared folder...
There is also a warning in my shared folders classes' as Cannot fully validate since domain type path.to.my.server.Service class is not available.

Comment: Update: This worked perfectly when I did this inside the WindowsXP. Have problem in Ubuntu only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>shared</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <location>$%7BPARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC%7D/CloudSync-
                             AppEngine /shared</location>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

This is how your yourProject-Android/.project file should look like instead of having hard coded values inside it. I had errors because I copied the file to some other location.